# ice:selectBooleanCheckBox within ice:dataTable

Tags: jsf, data-binding, ejb-3.0, icefaces

in order to select the data i want to remove i put a selectbooleanCheckbox in each row of my dataTable, But the checkbox doesn't change state and it's always set to false even if i select the row (it works fine outside the dataTable). 
here's my backingBean:

```
    public class PermissionCtrl {

    //some attributes
    private UIData datas;
    private List<Permission> permissions;


    private UISelectBoolean checkbox ;

    @EJB
    private PermissionEjbLocal permissionService;


     //getters & setters


    public List<Permission> getSelectedPermissions() {

    Permission selectedRow = new Permission();
    int size = datas.getRowCount();

    List<Permission> selectedPermissions = new ArrayList<Permission>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        datas.setRowIndex(i);
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(checkbox.isSelected());
        if (checkbox.isSelected()) {

            selectedRow = (Permission) datas.getRowData();
            selectedPermissions.add(selectedRow);

        }

    }
    return selectedPermissions;
}

public String removeAction() {

    List<Permission> selectedPermissions = getSelectedPermissions();
    for (Permission p : selectedPermissions) {

        permissionService.removePermission(p);
    }
    this.permissions =  permissionService.getAllPermissions(); 

    return null;
}
    }
```

and this is the dataTable where i get the data:

```
    <ice:form>
    <ice:dataTable binding="#{permissionCtrl.datas}" value="#{permissionCtrl.permissions}" var="p">
            <ice:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <ice:outputText value="select" />
                </f:facet>
                <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{permissionCtrl.checkbox}"  />
            </ice:column>
            <ice:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <ice:outputText value="ID" />
                </f:facet>
                <ice:outputText value="test" />
            </ice:column>
            <ice:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <ice:outputText value="Label" />
                </f:facet>
                <ice:outputText value="#{p.label}" />

            </ice:column>

            <ice:column style="width:150px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <ice:outputText value="Url" />
                </f:facet>
                <ice:outputText value="#{p.url}" />

            </ice:column>


            <ice:column style="width:300px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <ice:outputText value="Description" />
                </f:facet>
                <ice:outputText value="#{p.description}" />

            </ice:column>
        </ice:dataTable>
    </ice:form>
```

did anyone ran into a similar issue? are there any errors in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have done is.. for all object you are binding with same variable,so the result would be last selection item.it would get overwrite till all objects arrived.

Solution is ::

make one persistent boolean property in Permission class like **isSelected**

put value with property like

```
<ice:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{permissionCtrl.checkbox}" value="#{p.selected}"/>
```

you will get value true or false in checkbox property in backing bean.

```
public List<Permission> getSelectedPermissions() {

    Permission selectedRow = new Permission();
    int size = datas.getRowCount();

    List<Permission> selectedPermissions = new ArrayList<Permission>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        datas.setRowIndex(i);
        selectedRow = (Permission) datas.getRowData();
        if (selectedRow.isSelected()) {
            selectedPermissions.add(selectedRow);
        }
    }
    return selectedPermissions;
}
```

Comment: got it and did what you recommended it me to do but i'm still having false as a value for the select attribute in the permission entity:

Comment: actually i'm having an stdout false for selectedRow.isSelected() and an Exception during phase execution.

Comment: 15:06:24,637 ERROR [lifecycle] JSF1054: (Phase ID: RENDER_RESPONSE 6, View ID: /permission/permission.jspx) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@1bde3f2]
15:06:24,638 ERROR [ReceiveSendUpdates] Exception occured during rendering on http://localhost:8080/RoleMgtWeb/block/send-receive-updates [/permission/permission.jspx]
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:128)


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: hi everyone, i managed to remove the selected permission from the dataBase, actually the dataTable and the commandeButton were in different forms that's why the checkbox didn't change its state. It's even working with checkbox binding. However i'm still having the exception. in Other words when i hit the removeAction button it removes the selected permissions and then i have that Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding all checkboxes to the same value in the backing bean, so later empty values will overwrite the initialy set value.

Keep a list of values and use the instance variable to adress it.

Comment: well it does work with jsf components i really don't understand why it's not working with icefaces components. it's not working with only one row which means there are no other values that could possibly overwrite the initialy set value.